# Adding new data when item is not available

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access-2007

Im very new on programming and Im having a difficult time thinking on how can I add new Item when Item Code does not exist on the database. It seems to run smoothly until I add else statement. here my code:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(@"Select * from TblInventory where ItemCode=itemcode");
            command.Connection = con;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemcode", txtItem.Text);

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows == true)
            {
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"Update TblInventory set Quantity = Quantity + @Quantity 
WHERE ItemCode = @itemcode");
                cmd.Connection = con;                   
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity",Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemcode", txtItem.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Data Saved !");
            }
            else
            {
                OleDbCommand cmdInsert = new OleDbCommand(@"insert into TblInventory (ItemCode,ProductName,Quantity)
values ('" + txtItem.Text + "','" + txtProduct.Text + "','" + txtQuantity.Text + "')");
                cmdInsert.Connection = con;
                cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("New Data Added");
            }

            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error  " + ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: sql injection alert

Comment: What happens when you run it?  Are you getting an error?  Have you checked to see what the insert query string looks like?  Are there single quotes in any of the text boxes you're using for data?

Comment: i find that in your `Select * from TblInventory where ItemCode=itemcode` its `itemcode` and not `@itemcode`.

Comment: sir @PhillipXT i dont get any error but when i add a new itemcode it doesn't go on the else statement.

Comment: I try to change **if (reader.HasRows == true)**  >>>  **if (reader.Read())** but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

One of the best way to find existing record in database is to count the number of given record criteria.

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(@"Select COUNT(ItemCode) from
                                          TblInventory where ItemCode= @itemcode");
```

Then use `ExecuteScalar()` instead of `ExecuteReader()`

```
Int32 count = (int32) command.ExecuteScalar();
```

`ExecuteScalar()` returns the first column of the first row of your query result which is the count of your `itemCode`. You can read in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

Then you can do the simple conditional logic.

```
if (count > 0) // means that itemCode has 1 or more record count found in the db.
{
     // Do the update logic here..
}
else
{
     // Do the insert logic here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I already found the answer.
FROM THIS:

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(@"Select * from TblInventory where ItemCode=itemcode");
```

TO THIS:

```
 OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(@"Select * from TblInventory where ItemCode='" + txtItem.Text + "'");
```

Comment: That's bad, you are prone to error with sql injection. if you input a char like '  your query will crashed. the only reason your query doesn't return a value because in the clause `ItemCode=itemcode` you missed to define a parameter you should write this instead `ItemCode=@itemcode` so the code line `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemcode", txtItem.Text);` will assign a certain value to `@itemcode`. This will solved your problem more effectively.